# QtIFW установка со структурой директорий

Tags: qt

Добрый день. Имеется ли возможность создать установщик с помощью Qt Installer Framework такой, чтобый он распаковывал содержимое по нужным папкам. Например, чтобы установщик создавал следующее дерево:

```
target_dir
   bin
   config
   Readme.txt
```

В папке bin должны лежать исполняемые файлы, в config - конфиги.

Comment: В папку data корневого компонента кладите ваши bin, config и readme и будет вам счастье. Если я правильно понял задачу :)

Comment: Да, действительно, все работает, надо было сразу так попробовать :)

Answer (score 0):

А вот если один пакет надо установить в program Files, а другой в Application Data. Как быть тогда? Путь задается только в config.xmp, а в package.xml пакетов путей нет. Или я плохо читал:
https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-component-description.html#package-information-file-syntax

Comment: Если вы хотите задать новый вопрос, воспользуйтесь кнопкой  [Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)